# Why regular expression is stuck?

Tags: python, regex, regex-group, python-re

I've incrementally updated a regular expression to cleanup a data and found it runs infinity long for the string. It's a Python code to test.

```
import re

re.sub(r'(([-.]?\d+)|(\d+))+$', '', 'bcn16-01081-210300-16-20160829-ca')
```

I suppose it's because of duplicates of `\d+` in groups because it became working if reg exp is simplified to `([-.]\d+|\d+)+$`. But I want to know more precise. Anybody knows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `(([-.]?\d+)|(\d+))+$`, both `[-.]?\d+` and `\d+` are practically matching the same strings. When a `+` is applied on the right, the expression starts behaving in a similar way to the [notorious `(a+)*$` pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS).

Use

```py
[-.]?\d+(?:[-.]\d+)*$
```

`([-.]\d+|\d+)+$` is still catastrophic backtracking prone because of nested `+`. See more about [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) (and [here](https://community.appway.com/screen/kb/article/checking-strings-avoiding-catastrophic-backtracking-1482810891360)).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [-.]?                    any character of: '-', '.' (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [-.]                     any character of: '-', '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: It works perfect. Thank you!
Also thank you for telling about catastrophic backtracking.